# Traceback with argparse and ArgumentError

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using Python version 3.10.1. I'm trying to use the `argparse` library to handle arguments, including handling invalid arguments gracefully. However, I'm encountering a mind-boggling traceback. Here's the problem code:

```
import argparse

def check_positive(value):
    try:
        value = int(value)
        if value <= 0:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(f"{value} is not a positive integer.")
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentError("Score threshold must be a positive integer.")
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)
    parser.add_argument("file", help="a help message")
    parser.add_argument("score_threshold", type=check_positive, help="another help message")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

As a test, I specify the argument -102 as the score threshold. This should enter the if statement, and then raise the `argparse.ArgumentError`. However, in doing so, I encounter another exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 2479, in _get_value
    result = type_func(arg_string)
  File "<snip>", line 151, in check_positive
    raise argparse.ArgumentError(f"{value} is not a positive integer.")
TypeError: ArgumentError.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<snip>", line 166, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 1821, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 1859, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 2066, in _parse_known_args
    stop_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 2022, in consume_positionals
    take_action(action, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 1915, in take_action
    argument_values = self._get_values(action, argument_strings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 2446, in _get_values
    value = self._get_value(action, arg_string)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\argparse.py", line 2492, in _get_value
    raise ArgumentError(action, msg % args)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument score_threshold: invalid check_positive value: '-102'
```

I have absolutely no idea why Python is complaining. I'm utterly baffled. Aren't I handling the error as expected? It should simply raise the `argparse.ArgumentError` and print `-102 is not a positive integer.` Also, I have no idea what the hell `TypeError: ArgumentError.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` means. I should only need to provide an error message, right? Is there some change to `argparse.ArgumentError` that I'm not aware of? Searching the Internet has yielded zero fruit, so I'm really scratching my head on this.

Answer (score 2):

The init for `ArgumentError` is

```
def __init__(self, argument, message):
   ...
```

That's why you get `TypeError: ArgumentError.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` when you only provide one argument.

Look in the `argparse.py` code to see examples of where `ArgumentError` is raised.  In `_get_value

The developer's intentions that an error in `type` function should raise a `ArgumentTypeError`.  In `_get_value` this class of error is caught, and converted to an `ArgumentError`.

```
def _get_value(self, action, arg_string):
    type_func = self._registry_get('type', action.type, action.type)
    if not callable(type_func):
        msg = _('%r is not callable')
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg % type_func)

    # convert the value to the appropriate type
    try:
        result = type_func(arg_string)

    # ArgumentTypeErrors indicate errors
    except ArgumentTypeError:
        name = getattr(action.type, '__name__', repr(action.type))
        msg = str(_sys.exc_info()[1])
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg)

    # TypeErrors or ValueErrors also indicate errors
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        name = getattr(action.type, '__name__', repr(action.type))
        args = {'type': name, 'value': arg_string}
        msg = _('invalid %(type)s value: %(value)r')
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg % args)
```

TypeError and ValueError which are produced by functions like `int` and `float`, are converted to a standardized error message.  The `ArgumentTypeError` message is passed through unchanged.

The long traceback just shows how far down the `parse_args` calling stack this error occurs.

These two exception classes are simple, and relatively clear in the `argparse.py` code, but not documented.

Under `type` the documentation says:

```
The argument to type can be any callable that accepts a single 
string. If the function raises ArgumentTypeError, TypeError, or 
ValueError, the exception is caught and a nicely formatted error 
message is displayed. No other exception types are handled.
```

And with the addition of the `exit_on_error=False` parameter, there are few code examples with `ArgumentError`.

Since few people have tried to do what you've done, you won't find any help on a "internet search".  That's only useful for common, but "unique" errors.  For this kind of error, studying the `argparse.py` code is the only option.